# 'app.use() requires a middleware function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I was making a registration and Login page for user in Node using express. When i try to run my app.js file it gives this "**app.use()**" error. Below is my app.js code

```js
const express= require("express");
const app= express();
const path= require("path");
const hbs= require("hbs");
var session= require("express-session");
const { urlencoded } = require("express");
const port= process.env.PORT || 3000;
require("dotenv").config;
const static_path= (path.join(__dirname,"../public"));
const template_path= (path.join(__dirname,"../templates/views"));
const partials_path= (path.join(__dirname,"../templates/partials"));
const db= require("./db/db.js");
const cookieParser= require("cookie-parser");
const e = require("express");
hbs.registerPartials(partials_path);
var regisRouter= require("../src/routes/regis");
var loginRouter= require("../src/routes/login");
var dashbRouter= require("../src/routes/dashboard");
var logoutRouter= require("../src/routes/logout");

app.use('/regis',regisRouter);
app.use('/login',loginRouter);
app.use('/dashboard',dashbRouter);
app.use('/logout',logoutRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
  });
   
  // error handler
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
   
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
  });


app.use(express.static(static_path));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use("cookieParser()");

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views",template_path);

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret123",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: oneDay}
}));


app.get("/",(req,res) =>{
    session= req.session;
    if(session.id)
    {
        res.send("Welcome User <a href=\'/logout'>click to logout</a>");    
    }
    else
       res.render("index");
});

// app.post("/register", async(req,res) =>{
//     try {
//         const password= req.body.password;
//         const cpassword= req.body.confirmpassword;
//         if(password===cpassword)
//         {

//         }
//         else
//         {
//             res.send("invalid login credentials");
//         }
//     } catch (error) {
//         res.status(400).send(error);
//     }
// });

app.listen(port,() =>{
    console.log(`this is port no. ${port}`);
});
```

I think probably this part has an error, but i am not so sure about it

```js
app.use('/regis',regisRouter);
app.use('/login',loginRouter);
app.use('/dashboard',dashbRouter);
app.use('/logout',logoutRouter);
```

Below is the folder structure if it is of any help

[image: folder-structure]

I am not able to understand this error. If someone could tell me it would be of great help , thankyou!

Comment: Which line throws the error? What is the **exact** error

Comment: `app.use("cookieParser")` is passing a string not a middleware function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have to pass a function as a parameter to `app.use()`, but you are giving a string into it `"cookieParser()"`.

### Change

```
app.use("cookieParser()");
```

### To

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```